# How do I resize multiple canvas apps independently of each other?

Tags: visualforce, canvas

I have two canvas apps on the contacts page, but when I resize one app via `Sfdc.canvas.client.resize()`, the other app resizes as well. My first app is resizing every 500ms to the current `contentHeight` of that shell, and the second app is resizing just once to a set height of 500px.

What's happening is that the first shell automatically gets resized to 500px as well as the second shell, and when I try to resize the first shell to a different height, it automatically pops back to 500px.

I've checked the client objects for each shell and they have different `instanceId`'s, so I'm unclear as to why the resizing for one shell is interfering with a different shell.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of doing same is handling resize in the visualforce page than doing the same via client side logic .

Here is the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_vf_resize_code_example.htm) for same

The sample code is as follows

```
// Set the height and width explicitly and target a canvas app
 // Where 'mycanvas0' is the canvasId on the canvas component 
  // <apex:canvasApp canvasId="mycanvas0"/>
      var target = {canvas : "mycanvas0"};
    Sfdc.canvas.controller.resize( {height : "1000px", width : "900px"}, target);
```